# json schema usage of definitions keyword

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Can anyone please help me with usage of definitions in json schema. I had gone through their [website](http://json-schema.org)  and didn't get much information.

Any helps would be worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the definitions keyword is a standardized placeholder in which you can define inline subschemas to be used in a schema.

In other words, the definitions keyword *defines* subschemas that you can refer to elsewhere in the schema. Perhaps this is an easier example:

```
"properties": {
    "cars": {
        "type": "object",
        "oneOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/ford" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/bmw" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/audi" }
        ]
    }
},
"definitions": {
    "ford": {
        "origin": "USA"
     },
    "bmw": {
        "origin": "Germany"
    },
    "audi": {
        "origin": "Germany"
    }
}
```

Under `definitions` you *define* subschemas, for example for `ford` that you can refer to elsewhere with `"$ref": "#definitions/ford"`.

Comment: Can we use `$ref` inside` dependencies` block?

Comment: to be clear, is this just a convention? Is there a diferrence between this an $defs?

Comment: definitions was used prior the introduction of the $defs keyword in draft 2019-09 (Draft 8)

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-02#appendix-G